# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor porcentaje y ademas realizar el calculo?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, funciones

```
//Creo una función donde voy a sumar todos los valores totales de la última columna
var sumaTotalesDetalleGastoGeneral = function(){
  //Inicializo en 0 el valor a establecer indicando el resultado de la sumatoria
var totales = 0;
//Recorro todas las filas de la tabla
$('tr','#tablaDetalleGastoGeneral').each(function(){
 //Obtengo el campo del cual quiero tomar el valor para sumarlo
 var campo_total = $(this).find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');
 //Agrego a totales el nuevo valor
 var numero = parseInt(campo_total.val()); totales += isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero; 
});
//Establezco el resultado de la suma
$('#detalle_gastos_generales').val(totales);
$('#suma_3').val(totales);
};



//Esta tabla es para agregar Detalle materiales, repuestos e insumos
var sumaDetalleGastoGeneral = function(){
//Obtengo la última fila ingresada en la tabla
var fila = $('#tablaDetalleGastoGeneral').find('tr:last');
//Obtengo el campo referente a la cantidad de insumo ':eq(2)'
var campo1 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(2)'); 
//Obtengo el campo referente al precio_unitario_insumo ':eq(3)'
var campo2 = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(3)');
//Obtengo el campo donde se escribirá el resultado
var destino = fila.find('input[type="text"]:eq(4)');

campo1.on('change', function(){
  destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
    //Llamo a la función para que se actualice cada vez que se cambie algo en este campo
    sumaTotalesDetalleGastoGeneral();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  });

   campo2.on('change', function(){
   destino.val(parseInt(campo1.val())*parseInt(campo2.val()));
     //Llamo a la función para que se actualice cada vez que se cambie algo en este campo
    sumaTotalesDetalleGastoGeneral();
    sumaTotalGeneral();
  }); 
};

function funcNuevaDetalleGastoGeneral() 
{
  $("#tablaDetalleGastoGeneral")
 .append
(
  $('<tr>')
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'detalle_gasto_general[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'unidad_gasto_general[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>')
    .append
    (
      $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'cantidad_gasto_general[]')
      )
    )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'precio_gasto_general[]')
    )
   )
  .append
  (
   $('<td>')
   .append
   (
    $('<input>').attr('type', 'text').addClass('form-control').attr('name', 'valor_total_gasto_general[]').prop('readonly', true)
    )
   )
  .append
  (
    $('<td>').addClass('text-center')

    .append
    (
      $('<div>').addClass('btn btn-danger').text('Eliminar')
      )            
    )    

  );

sumaDetalleGastoGeneral();
}
```

## GASTOS GENERALES

DESCRIPCION
        PORCENTAJE
        SUB TOTAL
        TOTAL
      
      
        GASTOS GENERALES
        
        
        
      
      
        UTILIDAD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Monsines, bienvenido a SOes. Puedo ver que literalmente solo copiaste todo tu codigo (con todo y comentarios) y lo pegaste en la pregunta. Te recomiendo dos cosas: simplifica tu codigo segun las recomendaciones en el articulos [mcve] y despues trata de explicar que es lo que necesitas. Saludos!

Comment: @Dariel Ramos Diaz esta es mi duda que tengo, que aun me ha costado un poco. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola si lo que requieres es como calcular el porcentaje lo obtienes multiplicando el valor del sub total por el porcentaje que requieres ejemplo 100*0,10= 10% entonces si son **15532*0,01=155.32** y eso lo almacenas en una variable y luego se lo restas o sumas según lo que necesites. espero te sirva saludos

Comment: Es tema de codigo por que la formula me la sé, gracias de todas maneras